# Can I specify subdomains to block or allow with Windows Parental Control?

Tags: windows-7

With Windows Parental Control (www.account.microsoft.com/family) is it possible to distinguish **sub**domains?

Specifically I want to allow [Google Translate (translate.google.com)](https://translate.google.com/) but block [Google news (news.google.com)](https://news.google.com/).

Or even better allow all google.com subdomains but disallow Google News.

I can only add another allowed sites, I can't in same time add disallowed sites.

Comment: While Parent Control has many features it is limited.  It sounds your specific needs go beyond its capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 doesn’t have a Web Filter included (Vista had). Install Windows Live [Family Safety](http://fss.live.com) which is part of the Window Live Essentials suite for Web Filtering and activity reports.There you can block access to certain sites and also get access to an activity report that shows you what sites your children have been visiting.
...

*To allow or block specific websites*

```
Sign in to family on the Microsoft account website.

Select the child you want to turn on web browsing limits for.

Select Web browsing.

To add a site to their allow list, go to Always allow these and enter the URL of a website you want to allow.

To add a site to their block list, go to Always block these and enter the URL of a website you want to block.
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm talking about Live Family Safety. (i didn't name it but i wrote about www.account.microsoft.com/family with is Live Family Safety i think.

Comment: Edited to cover explicit allow and block of websites in Windows Live Family Safety. Hope it helps. You can always use Group Policy, HOSTS file, Blocking via Browser and other methods to disallow site being opened